# How to combine these 2 MySQL select queries to one to prevent looping?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am rewriting all old mysql-functions to prepared statements (PDO). I also try to rewrite all sql inside loops, making queries "smart", so sql-loops are not needed anymore. But this one, i have no clue how to accomplish this.

Simple SQL for searching used ip addresses:

```
SELECT ip FROM log_ip WHERE spelerID = :spelerID
```

Usually i do a while-loop on the result: for every found ip address i do a new sql search for finding other users on the same ip-address.

```
SELECT spelerID,naam FROM log_ip WHERE ip = :ip
```

I could not find a solution to create 1 query, to find users, using the same ip address?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which, in this case, is also a "self join":

```
SELECT l1.ip, l2.spelerID, l2.naam
FROM log_ip l1
LEFT OUTER JOIN log_ip l2
  ON l2.ip = l1.ip
  AND l2.spelerID <> l1.spelerID
WHERE l1.spelerID = :spelerID
```

Now, mind you, the results are going to look a little different than what you might be used to. The l1 `ip` value will repeat.

You should investigate the `JOIN` clause and loop over the results in your application rather than looping queries.

Comment: #1052 - Column 'spelerID' in where clause is ambiguous. In where i changed to l1.spelerID and...YESSSSSSSSSSSS. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Also thanks for the explanation. Accpeted your answer and clicked on usefull too:) Thanks again:)